# Issue with custom script to sort Arrays ascending and descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an issue to deal with here (a logical error in my code 99%). I just can't seem to find the way to fix it, but I bet one of you will find the problem in no time!

I have to create a function which sorts array passed to it in asc or desc order, but can't use any array sorting functions !

I've been struggling with loops until now and I finally want to ask help from other devs ( you ).

Currently only code for ascending is worked on, descending will be no problem I assume once I do this one. It kinda of does sort values up to some point, but then stops ( it stops if the next smallest value is at the end of the passed array ). What could I do to prevent this and make it sort the whole array and it's elements?

Here is the code so far.

```
<?php

function order_array($array,$mode = 'ascending') {

    $length = count($array);

    if($mode == 'descending') {     
        return $array;
    } else {

        $sorted_array = array();
        $used_indexes = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $smallest = true;

            echo $array[$i] . '<br/>';
            for($y = 0; $y < $length; $y++) {

                //echo $array[$i] . ' > ' . $array[$y] . '<br/>';
                // if at ANY time during checking element vs other ones in his array, he is BIGGER than that element
                // set smallest to false
                if(!in_array($y,$used_indexes)) {
                    if($array[$i] > $array[$y]) {
                        $smallest = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($smallest) {
                $sorted_array[] = $array[$i];
                $used_indexes[] = $i;
            }

        }

        return $sorted_array;
    }
}

$array_to_sort = array(1, 3, 100, 99, 33, 20);
$sorted_array = order_array($array_to_sort);
print_r($sorted_array);

?>
```

Comment: Did you even read my post ? Retorical question since I know you did not. It is clearly stated NO array sorting functions

Comment: ok, sory but you can keep sort ascending and only return the array from the end to the first element (using count)

Comment: can you give me an example of where i would need to do this ? Or point me to the part of my code that has the logical error in it ?

Comment: i post an answer, hope you understand from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue myself by doing it completely different. Now it sorts correctly all the elements of the passed in array. The logical issue I had was of using for() loop. The for() loop ran only a set ( length of passed array ) number of times, while we need it to loop more than that, because we will need to loop all the way untill we have a new sorted array in ascending order. Here is the code that will work

```
function order_array($array,$mode = 'ascending') {

    if($mode == 'descending') {

        // for() wont work here, since it will only loop an array length of times, when we would need it
        // to loop more than that.
        while(count($array)){
            $value = MAX($array); 
            $key = array_search($value, $array); 

            if ($key !== false) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
            $sorted[] = $value;
        }

        return $sorted;

    } else {

        // for() wont work here, since it will only loop an array length of times, when we would need it
        // to loop more than that.
        while(count($array)){
            $value = MIN($array); 
            $key = array_search($value, $array); 

            if ($key !== false) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
            $sorted[] = $value;
        }


        return $sorted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function order_array($array,$mode = 'ascending') {

    $length = count($array);



        $sorted_array = array();
        $used_indexes = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $smallest = true;

            echo $array[$i] . '<br/>';
            for($y = 0; $y < $length; $y++) {

                //echo $array[$i] . ' > ' . $array[$y] . '<br/>';
                // if at ANY time during checking element vs other ones in his array, he is BIGGER than that element
                // set smallest to false
                if(!in_array($y,$used_indexes)) {
                    if($array[$i] > $array[$y]) {
                        $smallest = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            if($smallest) {
                $sorted_array[] = $array[$i];
                $used_indexes[] = $i;
            }


         if($mode == 'descending') {

            return array_reverse($sorted_array);
        }

        return $sorted_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will help me with 'descending' mode, but you didnt quite understand my problem :) I would know how to do it in descending mode, the thing is that the code I did for ASCENDING mode, is not sorting ALL of the passed array elements. Try it in your text editor and you will see what I mean

Comment: ok , what i mean is that you need to develop it only once for desc or asc and in the other option all you need is to return it reverse

Comment: I understand that, but try to run the code for Ascending mode. I have problems in making it work correctly.